# Why my Symfony route is overridden by other routes?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I use annotations to define routes in my project. I have a controller method that has such a route:

```
/**
* @Route("/{slug}", name="showcompany")
*/
public function show(Company $company): Response
{
...
}
```

This is done to catch requests like `website.com/company1`, `website.com/company2`, etc...

I get this error:

> "App\Entity\Company object not found by the @ParamConverter
> annotation."

Since obviously all other routes such as website.com/signup are considered as `slugs` of the Company entity.

The question is how to avoid this behavior without moving all routes to `routes.yaml` and ordering them manually? I want all routes to be prioritized over this `/{slug}` route.

Comment: Starting in 5.1 you can add a [route priority](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#priority-parameter).  For older versions of Symfony, you can still use a yaml file to create this particular route and then ensure it gets loaded last.  There are actually a number of almost identical question out there.  Search first and avoid the lectures and down votes.

Comment: @Cerad thank you! This actually solves my question, could you please post it as an answer?